# Get all unique words from a string using regex

Tags: regex

I have the following string: `Cup, Plate, Plate, Cup, Spoon, Cup` and I will like to only get Cup, Plate, Spoon.

I was wondering if this is possible using regex match?

I have tried using the `/(\w+\b)(?!.*\1\b)/` using first regex match but it only returns Cup. I am using jquery for my regex syntax.

Comment: Probably the best way with regex is getting unique items with `\b(\w+)\b(?!.*\b\1\b)` and then `join` the items obtained with `', '`. There are *plenty of* SO answers for specific programming languages. Which is yours?

Comment: Pure regex alone can't really do this.  Are you using regex from some programming language?

Comment: Noticed JQuery in the question, so it is JS.

Comment: Guessed as much that it will be tricky to achieve this using regex match.. using simple jqeury expressions (JS)